# Yesod Compare getCurrentRoute to a route with dynamic parameters

Tags: haskell, yesod

A question of coding haskell with good form, instead of 'it works'.

We want our menu navigation items to have a highlighted CSS class when the user is on that page.

Easy.

Here are my routes:

```
...
/simple SimpleR GET POST
/search SearchFormR GET POST
/searchresults/#Int/#Text SearchResultsR GET 
...
```

In my hamlet template I have the below. This works perfectly, the link is highlighted when the user is on that page. The route is simple.

```
<li .nav-item>
    <a .nav-link :Just SimpleR == mcurrentRoute:.active href=@{SimpleR}>
        Simple page
```

This link should be highlighted when the user is on either of `SearchFormR` or `SearchResultsR`.

```
<li .nav-item>
   <a .nav-link :((Just (SearchResultsR _ _)) == mcurrentRoute) || (Just SearchFormR == mcurrentRoute):.active href=@{SearchFormR}>
       Search
```

This code does not work, because the `SearchResultsR` route constructor needs the two things passed to it. I cannot write `_ _` as I have above, since the constructor needs a literal value. And besides, the result of the constructor will be compared with `==` to the actual route anyway, it won't match unless both parameters happen to be the exact same.

Without the `_ _` I of course get a type error, expecting two more things passed to the `SearchResultsR` constructor.

That is, I want to check if we are on any `SearchResultsR` route, not only match `SearchResultsR 123 "abc"`.

My first thought was to make a function to convert the route to a string and then check if that string contains the string of the route, but this is bad, and not the haskell / typesafe way.

My second attempt is using pattern matching:

Foundation.hs:

```
isThisRouteSearchResultsR :: Maybe (Route App) -> Bool
isThisRouteSearchResultsR (Just (SearchResultsR _ _)) = True
isThisRouteSearchResultsR _ = False
```

Hamlet template:

```
<li .nav-item>
   <a .nav-link :(isThisRouteSearchResultsR mcurrentRoute) || (Just SearchR == mcurrentRoute) :.active href=@{SearchR}>
       Search
```

But this doesn't seem much better. What if I have a lot more routes that have dynamic parts?
What is the proper way to do this? I looked at haskellers site source code but couldn't find the answer

Comment: I like your second approach. Infact, I would even refactor that into a single function such that you don't do the `|| (Just SearchR == mcurrentRoute)` in the hamlet file. The goal is to usually keep all your logic in the Haskell file and keep it minimal in the Hamlet file. If you have more dynamic parts, I would just create a single function to handle them (ie compose lots of single function to do what I want).

Comment: Thanks for the kudos Sibi! The tip about "the goal is usually" is really valuable. I want to do things the Yesod way. Interesting, I think I do not fully understand, what would the return type of the single function be? I thought of returning a string like "SearchResultsR" to compare against, but this seems messy.

Comment: The return type will be `Bool`.

Comment: Thank you. An example: `:(isThisRouteSearchResultsROrSearchR mcurrentRoute) :.active` Or could do `:(isThisRouteSearchResultsR mcurrentRoute) || (isThisRouteSearchR mcurrentRoute) :.active` Perhaps these functions could be generated automatically in Foundation.hs by some Template Haskell.

Comment: That's right. I would prefer the first solution `:(isThisRouteSearchResultsROrSearchR mcurrentRoute) :.active`, but that's just me. I wouldn't reach to Template Haskell for this as this is quite simple (and readable)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by Sibi in the comments (thank you Sibi) is that the second approach in the question is in good form / style.

e.g. in hamlet:
`:(isThisRouteSearchResultsROrSearchR mcurrentRoute) :.active`

Or could do 
`:(isThisRouteSearchResultsR mcurrentRoute) || (isThisRouteSearchR mcurrentRoute) :.active`

And you define these functions in Foundation.hs (Haskell) as per the question code.

Sibi:

> The goal is to usually keep all your logic in the Haskell file and
>   keep it minimal in the Hamlet file.

Thank you Sibi for your guidance.